# Server unable to process request error when loading XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read from an XML file and when I try and load it using an `XmlDocument` I get this error:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults`(either from `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` or from the `<serviceDebug>` configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Here is the code that causes this:

```
public string calorieCount(int choice)
  {
    string calCount = "250";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    //ERROR WITH LINE BELOW. no error without.
    doc.LoadXml("XMLFile1.xml");

    //XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    //XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/menu/item[@name='Burger']/calories");
    //string checker = node.Value;
    //MessageBox.Show(checker);
    return calCount;
}
```

It seems as though no matter what path I place in there it doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I have done the following and the error persists, I have updated the service reference and it still gives me this error.

```
<behavior name="debug">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
</behavior>
```

and

```
<services>
 <service name="calorieCount" behaviorConfiguration="debug"></service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do just as the error message says.

Add to your service -

```
 <services>
      <service name="YourServiceName" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
  </services>
```

Add to your config file

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="debug">
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

**EDIT**:

1. If this doesn't fix your issue, turn the tracing on.
2. Ensure service name has full name eg: Namespace.ClassName
3. Ensure contract has full name eg: Namespace.ClassName

Comment: Have you recycled the application pool that the web service uses after making the configuration change?

Comment: @Andy: if you are still getting that same error message, then you haven't turned this on for the service.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I haven't...Doing it now

Comment: @Dijkgraaf How do I do this? I have updated the service reference in the application and it still does not work.